# MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1.0 questions

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are in process of upgrading our platform from WL 6.2.0.1 to MFP 7.1.0. And I have some queries:

1. Do I need to build .wlapp and native binaries for each server I have (Dev-QA..etc) or I can do one build and deploy to different servers, since each one of them has a different server URL?
2. Does IBM has a scope for Apple watch support, or do we still need to go as native?
3. In terms of security test, Does MFP has a security test for mobile web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you have several servers, that you probably also have a load balancer. Your app is supposed to point to the load balancer and the load balancer then redirects traffic to the server(s).
2. There is no official Apple Watch support at this time, but you can create apps for the watch. See multiple blog posts at the Developer Center: http://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/blogs
3. There is no specific [security test](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding_predefined_worklight_authentication_realms_and_security_tests11?lang=en) for it. You treat it like any other mobile environment.

Be sure to read thoroughly about MobileFirst Platform 7.0 and 7.1 [in the knowledge center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNJXP/welcome.html) (the what's new sections), as it is contains numerous changes since 6.2, such as the way Direct Update works, the introduction of Java adapters, the server now being session independent (meaning you cannot use global variables in adapters) and more...

Comment: Thanks Idan, for point "1" I don't have load balancer, we are treating each environment as separate server, which has a specific server URL. I thought we can control the wlapp on WAS level like a property for example that can be changed.

Comment: The server IP does not sit in the wlapp. It sits in the actual apk/ipa file. In the app. I don't understand how can you have a single app that connects to multiple IP address. There should be a server at the front that redirects the requests.

Comment: I see, so I can use the same wlapp across different servers but the apk/ipa are still environment specific.